# Create update task for tx_scheduler_task and fill field serialized_task_object correctly

Tags: typo3

I created an update task for table tx_scheduler_task: Old tasks get removed, new ones should be add.

I stumbled upon a problem in my attempt to write data to the field serialized_task_object.

```
$queryBuilder = $this->getDbQueryBuilder();
$queryBuilder
    ->insert('tx_scheduler_task')
    ->values(
        [
            'uid' => 1337,
            'nextexecution' => 1337,
            'serialized_task_object' => 'I_DO_NOT_KNOW_WHAT_TO_WRITE_HERE',
            'lastexecution_context' => 'CLI'

        ]
    )
    ->execute();
```

I created all new needed tasks inside development environment and copied the content to the update task for exmaple: "O:51:"TYPO3\CMS\Scheduler\Task\TableGarbageCollectionTask":10:s:9:"allTables";b:1;s:12:"numberOfDays";i: ..."

The update task just runs fine, but whatever I did I recieved the following error when I opened the module scheduler: "(1/1) TypeError get_class() expects parameter 1 to be object, bool given"

This string needs to be converted, casted to blob? Can some tell me how? I tried hex2bin, pack and read too much other things. I also looked inside typo3/sysext/scheduler/Classes/Scheduler.php but did not understand, how it is written or how to use ['serialized_task_object' => Connection::PARAM_LOB] inside my insert().

I know, that I can easily create a sql dump of tx_scheduler_task and import this inside staging or live. In this attempt I would like to use only TYPO3 update wizards.

Answer (score 1):

To modify scheduler tasks you can use the class [TYPO3\CMS\Scheduler\Scheduler](https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/master/typo3/sysext/scheduler/Classes/Scheduler.php). Here you have various methods like [addTask](https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/master/typo3/sysext/scheduler/Classes/Scheduler.php#L64) or [removeTask](https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/master/typo3/sysext/scheduler/Classes/Scheduler.php#L228) which should be used to modify the database.

For your Upgrade Wizard you could use something like this:

```
$myTask = new \TYPO3\CMS\Scheduler\Task\IpAnonymizationTask();
$myTask->setDescription("My IP Anonymization Task");
// call other methods here to fully define the task

$scheduler = new \TYPO3\CMS\Scheduler\Scheduler();
$scheduler->addTask($myTask);
```

To delete existing tasks you have to list them by a query, there is no such method currently. An example you can find at the [TYPO3\CMS\Scheduler\Controller\SchedulerModuleController](https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/master/typo3/sysext/scheduler/Classes/Controller/SchedulerModuleController.php#L810-L876).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not going those this road but use the symfony commands. Those can be run via backend as well and are far better deployable.

Check out https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/CommandControllers/Index.html for the docs.

Working example from tt_address:

`Configuration/Commands.php`

```
return [
    'ttaddress:geocode' => [
        'class' => \FriendsOfTYPO3\TtAddress\Command\GeocodeCommand::class,
        'schedulable' => true,
    ],
];
```

and the command itself

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace FriendsOfTYPO3\TtAddress\Command;


use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;

/**
 * Command for geocoding coordinates
 */
class GeocodeCommand extends Command
{

    /**
     * Defines the allowed options for this command
     *
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this
            ->setDescription('Geocode tt_address records')
            ->addArgument(
                'key',
                InputArgument::REQUIRED,
                'Google Maps key for geocoding'
            );
    }

    /**
     * Geocode all records
     *
     * @inheritdoc
     * @return int
     */
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        // do stuff
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I can not see how your response helps me nor does it answer any of my questions.

Comment: Instead of using tasks with serialization you can also use commands for you CLI code - that's all